# Static files in a Snaplet

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, heist

I'd like to serve some static files from a Snaplet in the Snap framework.  How do I do that?  The documentation is not exactly clear.

I know how to add routes and stuff, but I'm stuck at two problems:

1. What would I need to pass to `serveDirectory` to serve files from the snaplet directory?
2. How would I reference these static files in Heist templates of my snaplet?  I obviously can't use absolute URLs, since I don't know the URL prefix my snaplet is eventually installed in the final application.  In other words, how do I get an URL relative to the snaplet root URL in a Heist template?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `serveDirectory` is what you would use to serve static files.  You might have a route like this:

```
route [("static", serveDirectory "myDir"), ...]
```

When you reference those files in templates, you have to use the route that you assigned.  So if you had a file `myDir/foo.js`, then in a template, you'd refer to it with `/static/foo.js`.

If you don't know your snaplet's base URL, you can get it with the [getSnapletRootURL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.13.3.1/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:getSnapletRootURL) function.  Then you can make that available in your templates with a Heist splice.

Comment: And what if the snaplet was not nested at `/`, but at `/foo/`?  How would I handle that?

Comment: If the above route command was inside said snaplet, then the template would need "/foo/static/foo.js".  Otherwise, no change.  The basic idea is that you should figure out what URL you have to put in your browser (or curl/wget) to get the page, and put that URL in your template.

Comment: Uhm, obviously, but the point is that I **do not know** the exact prefix.  It could be anything, and I need to figure it out **dynamically**.

Comment: You can use the [getSnapletRootURL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.13.3.1/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:getSnapletRootURL) function and create a splice that makes the information available inside a template.